Auto Blocker Issue on Samsung A05
I'm trying to enable USB debugging on a Samsung A05 but its greyed out.
I have Googled around and suggestions are that I use the Auto Blocker feature but its not available on my device.
I have updated to One UI 6.1.
Is there a way I can resolve this?
